# How to mutate Values inside a Array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, struct, mutation

I need to mutate the following array:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age = 0
    }

func showPersonArray() -> [Person] {

    var dataArray = [Person]()

    dataArray.append(Person(name: "Sarah_Yayvo", age: 29))
    dataArray.append(Person(name: "Shanda_Lear", age: 45))
    dataArray.append(Person(name: "Heidi_Clare", age: 45))

    return dataArray
}
```

How could I split the "name"-key into two keys: "givenName" and "familyName".
Some nice person gave me this code before:

```
let arraySeparated1 = dataArray.map { $0.substring(to: $0.range(of: "_")!.lowerBound) }
let arraySeparated2 = dataArray.map { $0.substring(from: $0.range(of: "_")!.upperBound) }
```

Is it possible to make the mutation inside the struct?
The function showPersonArray() is only for demo and test.
Maybe there is a way to work with a target struct, like this:

```
struct Persontarget {
    var familyname: String
    var givenName: String
    var age = 0
}

struct Person: Array -> [Persontarget]  {
    var name: String
    var age = 0

    // Here the split/mutating code

    return [PersonWithTwoNames]
}
```

Or with an String extension. Possibly my question sounds pretty newby-like, but i´m trying the whole day...
Thanks everyone!

Comment: You should use an array literal instead of repeated `.append` calls. It's much shorter and simpler (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write an initializer on the new `Person` type, which initializes it from the old person type (which I called `LegacyPerson`):

```
import Foundation

struct LegacyPerson {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

func getPersonArray() -> [LegacyPerson] {
    return [
        LegacyPerson(name: "Sarah_Yayvo", age: 29),
        LegacyPerson(name: "Shanda_Lear", age: 45),
        LegacyPerson(name: "Heidi_Clare", age: 45)
    ]
}

struct Person {
    let familyName: String
    let givenName: String
    let age: Int
}

extension Person {
    init(fromLegacyPerson person: LegacyPerson) {
        let index = person.name.range(of: "_")!
        self.init(
            familyName: person.name.substring(from: index.upperBound),
            givenName: person.name.substring(to: index.lowerBound),
            age: person.age
        )
    }
}

let people: [Person] = getPersonArray().map(Person.init)

people.forEach{ print($0) }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have to figure it out. I don´t really have access to the getPersonArray function. Because originally it´s a web query in json. But it looks like i could work with this.

Comment: So I have to implement the Person Extension in my web-json request?

Comment: @JoschHazard I have no clue because I have no idea what you're code is like. I'm going off by what you showed me.

Comment: There is something like a struct CustomStringConvertible. But this only returns Strings. Thought there is maybe something like that, which could return structs as well.

Comment: `CustomStringConvertible` is a protocol. It defines how types print themselves. I'm not sure what exactly you're getting at

Comment: Everyrhing is working fine now. I just had to adapt the  struct parameters inside the extension. Thank you very much, awesome solution!

Comment: @JoschHazard Accept the answer if your question has been solved

Answer (score 0):

Create a method or computer variable for your Person class that returns what you want.

```
func firstName() -> String {
    return self.substring(to: $0.range(of: "_")!.lowerBound)
}
```

You should not force cast though

Answer (score 0):

with help of computed property defined in an extension

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

let person = Person(name: "Maria_Terezia", age: 300)

extension Person {
    var names:[String] {
        get {
            return name.characters.split(separator: "_").map(String.init)
        }
    }
}

for name in person.names {
    print(name)
}
```

prints

```
Maria
Terezia
```